# How do I specify "where" when using the insert method for build blocks in word 10

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to add a custom building block at the click of a button in MS word 10. Below is the code currently attached to my activeX button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim objTemplate As Template
   Dim objBB As BuildingBlock

' Set the template to store the building block
  Set objTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate

' Access the building block through the type and category
  Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeCustom5) _
 .Categories("General").BuildingBlocks("Experience")

 ' Insert the building block into the document replacing any selected text.
   objBB.Insert Selection.Range
 End Sub
```

My problem is, as this code is invoked at the click of a button, the button becomes the "Selection.Range" and is thus replaced. I looked all around for alternate codes that mention of different "where" specification and found nothing.

I only found two links(can't find the urls in my history rightnow, will update shortly)

1. It mentioned "Paragraphs(1)" instead of "Selection.Range", but this
   is an absolute location while I would need something relative
   (Before the button)
2. Using InsertBefore method which I suppose applies only to text (it
   was used to insert text in the example) as when I tried it for
   building blocks it didnt work

P.S I'm relatively new to VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem with the following code, posting it for others who might drop by in the future.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim objTemplate As Template
   Dim objBB As BuildingBlock

   ' Set the template to store the building block
   Set objTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate

   ' Access the building block through the type and category
   Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeCustom5) _
  .Categories("General").BuildingBlocks("Experience")

  ' Insert the building block into the document replacing any selected text.
   Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
   objBB.Insert Selection.Range
  End Sub
```

Basically just added the following lines just before inserting the BuildingBlock

```
       Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
```

Thanks everyone for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

When in "Creation mode", goto the "properties" toolbox of your `CommandButton1`, change the property `TakeFocusOnClick` from **True** to **False**:

[image]

The focus will stay onto the paragraph you selected.

If you want it just after your CommandButton you can add the following at the end of your sub:

```
    ...
    CommandButton1.Select
    Selection.HomeKey wdLine
    objBB.Insert Selection.Range
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this makes things a little better but not perfect yet. As the document will finally be sent to users it might not always be possible to ensure the cursor is where the block is intended to be inserted. In such cases there would still be some confusion for the users. Any suggestions?

Comment: Understood, but I didn't see where you want to do the insert in your question. Is there any text, paragraph, item that could be looked for as reference to the insertion? You could look for a word or a sentence in your whole doc and insert in the right place.

Comment: It's relative to the button, basically just above it, anyways the problem has been solved. Thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: Ok, just updated my post to answer your last comment... even if you found by yourself.